# Putting a distribution into a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to find gradient of joint distribution with respect to mean, covarince. I have mean like

```
means = [tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(name = 'mu_%d' % i, loc=np.zeros(2), covariance_matrix=0.1 * np.eye(2))
       for i in range(2)]
```

Now if I find the joint distribution, I have the task of calculating its gradient. To use `tf.gradients()` everything must be in the form of tensor. So I tried converting means into tensor using `theta_ = tf.convert_to_tensor(means)` but it throws error saying i

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: [`<tf.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance 'mu_0' batch_shape=() event_shape=(2,) dtype=float64>, <tf.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance 'mu_1' batch_shape=() event_shape=(2,) dtype=float64>`]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Is there any other way around to calculate the gradient of distribution with respect to means, covariance?

Answer (score 0):

A tf.distribution is an object which you can not take the gradient with respect to. Instead you need to call one of its methods.

For instance:

```
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(...)
mean = dist.mean()

tf.gradients(mean, some_param)
```

In general, you would use the `.mean`, `.covariance` or even the `.log_prob` methods to create those respective tensors, and take gradients with respect to them.